# File Monitoring System Reactive Programming

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactivex, reactive

I am using C#.I am new to reactive programming.
Using  reactive programming, I want to create a folder monitoring system which will invoke if folder A contains any file if yes then it will grab that file & process it and move it in Folder B.
Let say, Folder A is empty first.User adds some files into folder A realtime. System detects that new files has been added & it will process it one by one or simultaneously.
I am not able to understand what should I use Create or Interval and after that where will be my processing code be written
Please help me

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Have a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fairly close:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () =>
            {
                var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\A");
                fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                return fsw;
            },
            fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                h => fsw.Created += h,
                h => fsw.Created -= h))
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));


query
    .Subscribe(x => File.Move(x.EventArgs.FullPath, Path.Combine(@"C:\B", x.EventArgs.Name)));
```

Comment: It's close but not yet there, because you never start `FileSystemWatcher` (with `EnableRaisingEvents` property).

Comment: @Evk - This time I tested it.

Comment: And why delay by 100ms?

Comment: @Evk - The act of copying files in Windows was leaving file handles open for a small period of time. The delay was needed to let the OS close the file before moving it.

Comment: Ok, but this will fail if I decide to say copy 2GB file there. Anyway, correct handling of `FileSystemWatcher` events is probably out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Evk - Yes, probably. I think you'd need to start polling the file to see if it is locked. Probably some sort of simple `.Retry()` might work.

Comment: The `.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)` serves another important purpose. Makes the processing of the file asynchronous regarding to the `FileSystemWatcher` event handler. Without it the [`InternalBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize) of the `FileSystemWatcher` can easily be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemWatcher` has a relatively small [`InternalBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize) (8 KB by default, 64 KB max), that can be easily exceeded if a burst of file system changes happens in a short time span, and the event handlers of the `FileSystemWatcher` are doing anything time consuming. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0#events-and-buffer-sizes) gives this advice:

> Keep your event handling code as short as possible.

The consequence of exceeding the buffer is severe: all buffered notifications are lost. This should be highly undesirable in most scenarios, if not outright unacceptable. So doing heavy file-moving operations synchronously on the same thread with the event invocation is something to avoid. An easy way to achieve the desirable asynchrony is by injecting a `Delay` between the handler and the subscription code. A more sophisticated approach is to queue the incoming notifications, and process each file either sequentially, or with a limited concurrency. The [`Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229099(v=vs.103)) operator can be used both for queuing and for concurrency control. Here is an example¹:

```
IObservable<Unit> query = Observable
    .Using(() =>
        {
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\A");
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            return fsw;
        },
        fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler,
            FileSystemEventArgs>(h => fsw.Created += h, h => fsw.Created -= h)
    )
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
    .Select(x => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        File.Move(x.EventArgs.FullPath, Path.Combine(@"C:\B", x.EventArgs.Name));
    })))
    .Merge(maxConcurrent: 2);

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

Task<Unit> task = query.ToTask(cts.Token); // Start the file-watching
```

The `Observable.Defer`+`Observable.Start` combo is used as a synchronous equivalent of the asynchronous `Observable.FromAsync` (because the `File.Move` method is synchronous).

¹ <sub>It is a modified version of Enigmativity's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732780/11178549).</sub>