# Dispose previous observable selectmany rx

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, idisposable

I'm monitoring a directory with the following setup:

```
var folder = new Subject();
folder.OnNext("somepath");

folder.SelectMany(FileMonitor)
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"Found: {x}"));

public IObservable<string> FileMonitor(string pathToWatch){
   return Observable.Create<string>(obs => {
     var dfs = CreateAndStartFileWatcher(pathToWatch,obs);
     () => dfs.Dispose();
   });
}
```

This works, but if I pass a new path to the subject, the previous FileMonitor is not disposed.

Is there a way to cancel/dispose the previously generated Observable?

It looks like I need: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html but this is not implemented in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, asking a question gives yourself new insights.
The solution is to use `switch` which *is* available, but only works on a Observable.

So it should be:

```
var folder = new Subject();
folder.OnNext("somepath");

folder.Select(FileMonitor)
  .Switch()
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"Found: {x}"));

public IObservable<string> FileMonitor(string pathToWatch){
   return Observable.Create<string>(obs => {
     var dfs = CreateAndStartFileWatcher(pathToWatch,obs);
     () => dfs.Dispose();
   });
}
```

Leaving this question for reference instead of removing it.

Comment: Make sure not to run lengthy operations synchronously with the `FileSystemWatcher`'s event handlers, otherwise its internal buffer may overflow, resulting to lost notifications. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732510/file-monitoring-system-reactive-programming/ "File Monitoring System Reactive Programming") question for more details.

Comment: You should really look at `Observable.Using` in the case rather than `Observable.Create`.